# Access a char in a string, Swift 3.x

Tags: swift, string, char

I can not find documentation on Apple's developer site. I have also been searching for the past few hours without a well-explained answer. I am trying to learn swift currently and I am trying to access a nth char in a string. In c++ I know you can do this with str[int value] ie.

`string str = "This is a test string";
cout << str[2] << endl;`

should print out "i" if I counted right. I am trying to do/find a way to do this in Swift and have not found an easy or way to do this. Is anyone able to help give some input?

Comment: print (str[2])  strings work like arrays

Comment: I tried that and got an error in the swift playground.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its pretty simple :

```
    let myText = Array("Hello World !!!".characters)
    print(myText[2]) // "l" will be printed
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought converting it to a char array might be the only way. I just wanted to make sure. Since C++ you can just access the String as if it is an array since it is.